# How to create project file in Free Pascal IDE?

Tags: ide, project, pascal, freepascal, fpc

I'm started to learn Free Pascal and stick to the simple yet important question: is it possible to create project in console Free Pascal IDE?

How could I compile two units into one program?

I've searched over Internet, but all links leads to the `Lazarus`, which is not the same thing as `Free Pascal IDE`...

My best clue would be is to use Makefiles, but as far as I can see, information on this is also very-very limited.

So how create and compile multi-unit Pascal programs in Free Pascal IDE then?

Comment: Why not just use Lazarus though?

Comment: I don't like Delphi style UI this Gimp like windows placement...

Comment: Lazarus doesn't work in a putty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textmode IDE has no project concept where a list of files is kept, OR any external build system.

Basically the autobuild capability of the compiler (that is built-in) is utilized, so pressing compile or build on the mainmodule(program) will compile the whole lot.

The main module can be set in compiler->primary file, so that compile will also work from non main modules.

However it is possible to have local IDE settings (primary file, directories, defines), by copying all fp.(cfg|dsk|ini) files from the FPC directory to your project dir, and then customizing them (from within the IDE).

One could regard the combination of a set of config files + a directory for the mainmodule as a project or solution.